# Why is SSH key for specific Host not used before catch-all?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to connect to Github (on a Mac) using a specific SSH key. When my .ssh/config file looks like this:

```
Host github.priv.com
  HostName github.com
  UseKeyChain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_gh_priv

Host *
  UseKeyChain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

it uses `id_rsa` when I run `ssh -T git@github.priv.com`, but when I use a specific host:

```
Host github.priv.com
  HostName github.com
  UseKeyChain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_gh_priv

Host github.com
  UseKeyChain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

it uses `id_gh_priv` when I run `ssh -T git@github.priv.com`.

What am I missing? I thought it's supposed to use the first config that matches.

*NOTE*: both keys are in the OSX keychain.

Comment: My current workaround is to add an additional ssh key with a separate config for `github.com`
```
Host github.com
  UseKeyChain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_gh_default
```